# How to take a String of LastName, FirstName and return FirstInitial.LastName

Tags: java

Expected **Input**: Doe, John

Expected **Output**: J. Doe

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {

         String z = "Doe, John";
         System.out.println(z);
         String y = formatName(name);
         System.out.println(y);
     }

     public static String formatName(String name) {
        String str[] = name.split(",");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(str[1].charAt(0));
        sb.append(". ");
        sb.append(str[0]);
        return sb.toString();
   }
```

My output is not as expected.

Comment: Split on `", "` not `","`...

Comment: `str[1].charAt(0) = space`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Match (Optional) White Space with `String.split` Regular Expression

You have a space after the comma in your input, you could modify your *regular expression* in `split` from

```
String str[] = name.split(",");
```

to

```
String str[] = name.split(",\\s*");
```

to match and remove *optional* white-space. After I made the above change I ran your code, and got the (expected) output

```
Doe, John
J. Doe
```

#### Trim the Leading White Space

***Alternatively***, you *could* `trim` `str[1]` before getting the first character like

```
sb.append(str[1].trim().charAt(0)); //<-- will also remove leading space
```

#### Regular Expression With a Compiled `Pattern`

***Another*** possible option is compiling a *regex* [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and using a [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) like

```
// Match (and group) one more characters followed by a "," and
// optional whitespace. Then match (and group) one character followed
// any number of optional characters.
private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+),\\s*(.).*");
public static String formatName(String name) {
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(name);
    if (m.matches()) {
        return String.format("%s. %s", m.group(2), m.group(1));
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said and for some reason it didn't work? did you keep the main method the same?

Comment: @Progamminnoob I changed `String y = formatName(name);` to `String y = formatName(z);`, you don't have a `name` variable (in your post).

Comment: oh duh haha, brain fart x 100000 thanks a lot elliot. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Another simple way to get FirstInitial.LastName**

Other than using split, you can use substring and based on the position of the comma `,`, manipulate the name to get the output:

```
String s = "Doe, John";

s = s.replace(" ", "");                                      //remove spaces
int i = s.indexOf(",");                                      //get pos of comma
String name = s.charAt(i+1) + ". " + s.substring(0, i);      //create name
```

---

**Output:**

```
J. Doe
```

Comment: @Progamminnoob You can take a look at this solution.

Comment: @user3473460 yes that would work to, but for my project I have to have it in a method :/

Comment: @Progamminnoob There is no conflict. Just enclose those codes in a method. Something like `public static String makeName(String s)` then return the `name`.

Answer (score 1):

`sb.append(str[1].charAt(0));` , index for `charAt()` should be 1 not 0 .

`String str[] = name.split(",");` will return  `[Doe,  John]`, notice the space before second element.

better yet use `split(", ")`

Answer (score 1):

I tried this based on what i understood. Use for loop and trim the items

```
public static String formatName(String name) {
        String str[] = name.split(",");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length ; i++){
            str[i] = str[i].trim();
            //System.out.println("+"+str[i]+"+");
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(str[1].charAt(0));
        sb.append(".");
        sb.append(str[0]);
        sb.append(".");
        return sb.toString().trim();
    }
```